# How to configure Luigi task retry correctly?

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to configure Luigi's retry mechanism so that failed tasks will be retried a few times. However, while the task is retried successfully, Luigi exits unsuccessfully:

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 2 ran successfully:
    - 1 FailOnceThenSucceed(path=/tmp/job-id-18.subtask)
    - 1 MasterTask(path=/tmp/job-id-18)
* 1 failed:
    - 1 FailOnceThenSucceed(path=/tmp/job-id-18.subtask)

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks
```

So the question is: how do I configure Luigi (I have installed version 2.3.3 with pip install) so that when a task fails once, but is then retried with success, then Luigi will exit successfully with `This progress looks :)` instead of fail with `This progress looks :(`?

Here is a minimal scheduler and worker config I've come up with, as well as tasks to demonstrate the behavior:

```
[scheduler]
retry_count = 3
retry-delay = 1

[worker]
keep_alive=true
```

mytasks.py:

```
import luigi


class FailOnceThenSucceed(luigi.Task):
    path = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.path)

    def run(self):
        failmarker = luigi.LocalTarget(self.path + ".hasfailedonce")
        if failmarker.exists():
            with self.output().open('w') as target:
                target.write('OK')
        else:
            with failmarker.open('w') as marker:
                marker.write('Failed')
            raise RuntimeError("Failed once")


class MasterTask(luigi.Task):
    path = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return FailOnceThenSucceed(path=self.path + '.subtask')

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(self.path)

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as target:
            target.write('OK')
```

Example execution:

`PYTHONPATH=. luigi --module mytasks MasterTask --workers=2 --path='/tmp/job-id-18'`

Comment: 'retry-delay' should be 'retry_delay' https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old issue of Luigi - where successful retried tasks were not marked as such when failed and then succeeded on retry:
https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1932

It was fixed in version 2.7.2:
https://github.com/spotify/luigi/releases/tag/2.7.2

I suggest you upgrade to the latest Luigi version, i.e. by running `pip install -U luigi`.